# Jquery file upload not working with Select2

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I am using jquery file upload - Blue imp.
https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

When i am adding file it want select drop down turn into select2

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
    {% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { 
      %}
        <tr class="template-upload fade">

            <td>
                <select name="" placeholder="Select file name" class="select2_category form-control" tabindex="1">
                  <option value="Select file name"></option>
                  <option value="">CNIC</option>
                  <option value="">Birth Certificate</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% } %}
    </script>
```

Add files button button generate from template.

Jquery file upload provide api for add file.

```
jQuery('#submit_form').bind('fileuploadadd', function(){
    jQuery("#submit-form-table select.select2_category").select2();

});
```

Its working fine with all. but the last iteration is not triggering SELECT2

Comment: I added a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is the following line is getting executed when each file is added, but before the elements from the template are actually added to the DOM:

```
jQuery("#submit-form-table select.select2_category").select2();
```

Since you are using a template with the jQuery File Upload, I assume you are using the UI version. That version adds a "fileuploadadded" event. (Notice the "ed" at the end.) I think you want to bind to that event, instead of the "fileuploadadd" event.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options):

> The **added** callback is the equivalent to the **add** callback and is
>   triggered after the upload template has been rendered and the
>   transition effects have completed.

Comment: Well Your answer is correct and i got the solution. I found fileuploadadd call back in api and its work fine

jQuery('#submit_form').bind('fileuploadadd', function(){
    jQuery("#submit-form-table select.select2_category").select2();

});

Thanks for answer :)